# A martingale associated with a solution of a stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

Assume $B_t$ is a standard real brownian motion defined on $\{\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\}$ and $X_t(y)$ satisfies the following SDE:

\begin{equation}
dX_t=-\cot X_tdt+dB_t \text{  with }X_0=y
\end{equation}

We know that the solution exists up to time $T(y):=\inf\{t;\sin X_t(y)=0\}$. Now fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$, define $Z_t:=X_{t\wedge T(x)}(x)$ and
\begin{equation}
Y_t:=P\{X_{T(Z_t)}(Z_t)=\pi\}
\end{equation}

Where $X_{T(y)}(y):=\lim_{t\uparrow T(y)}X_t(y)$.

How can I prove that $Y_t$ is a martingale?

I was reading some notes about SDEs where I found this claim.

Comment: This is a PSQ. What is your personal input?

Comment: What is $P$ in the definition of $Y_t$?

Comment: I am sorry for not being thorough. I have edited my question. I hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Following the definition of martingales and conditioning on $X_t$ proves the claim.